# How to avoid exponencial time cost with SQL Server SUM function?

Tags: sum, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I realized my query takes exponential time by every time I use SUM function...

For Example, the below code takes 2 seconds

```
SELECT sub.a, SUM(sub.b)
FROM (
   SELECT a, b, c 
   FROM temp
)sub 
GROUP BY a;
```

And using a second SUM now takes 4 seconds and so on...

```
SELECT sub.a, SUM(sub.b), SUM(sub.c)
FROM (
   SELECT a, b, c 
   FROM temp
)sub 
GROUP BY a;
```

it seems the subquery is bein executed again by every SUM I do, whether this is correct, what would be the best practice to avoid the time cost?

*example above is just representing in the most basic way the question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: No, this is completely wrong.**

When you run a query in SQL Server, the optimizer compiles it into the most efficient method it can find. You can see the result by clicking `Include Actual Execution Plan` in SSMS.

For the query you specify, it would typically do something like this:

1. It notes that the subquery can be inlined into the query, and does so:

```
SELECT sub.a, SUM(sub.b), SUM(sub.c)
FROM temp
GROUP BY a;
```

2. It then evaluates the best way to aggregate the table by `a` values. Let's assume there is no index at all, a `Hash Aggregate` would be most likely chosen here.
3. On execution, every row is fed into the Hash, which builds up an in-memory hash table, with `a` values as the key. Each row is looked up based on `a`, a key is added to the hash table if it hasn't been seen before. Then `b` and `c` values are added to that key.
4. Let's say you have an index on `a,b,c`. Now a much faster method is possible, called a Stream Aggregate, because now the values are passing through the Aggregate sorted by `a`.
5. Each row passes through the aggregate. If the `a` value is the same as the row before, it's `b` and `c` values are added to whatever we have so far. When the `a` value changes, the existing result is output, and we start aggregating again.

It is true that summing extra columns is extra overhead, but it's pretty small compared to reading the table of disk or hashing, which is only done once per the whole query.

Comment: thanks @Charlieface, I discovered into the execution plan the missing of a certain index into one of my 30 tables used in the complex query, so by adding it, it went into your point #4 and solved the exponential time consumming issue, its normal that every SUM adds extra time but exponentialy. At the end the SUM was not the problem, it was just trying to SUM over an even bigger set of results without an index.

Comment: Don't forget: columns that are just needed for results, not `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` can be in the `INCLUDE` part of the index